# Create dynamically a webpage according to variables and save it

Tags: php, url, web

I've created a website which takes the parameters of a query and I'd like to create and redirect to a webpage having as URL my_site/first_parameter-second_parameter.php

So far I am able to display in the browser the address of the page but the thing is that I don't know how to really create and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you can just create html files at the location that you receive? Ist that what you want?

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

You can then use your location inside fopen. (Make sure, that the user associated with the webserver has the access rights on that path).

And then you can write your contents into that file.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally handled through the .htaccess file for url rewriting. Generally, its one file that handles all the requests. There is a ton of questions already on the subject so I won't go into much detail.